# Horizontal listview with Cell Dragging/Rearranging

Tags: android

Do you guys know some "Horizontal" Listview with "Cell Dragging/Rearranging"?
Any lib?
I'm trying to implement a dragable ListView with one horizontal listview lib.
But I come not having much success.

Comment: have found any link?

Comment: @MayurR.Amipara You can do this with the recycler view:
[drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview](https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.4vtkx7tb9)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [FancyCoverFlow](https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow) library. It will be like a horizontal list view, but with cell dragging. You just need to set the animation rotation to 0 inside library.

Comment: Does FancyCoverFlow has Drag and drop Cell? 
I did not find this in the samples.

Comment: You have to implement it manually. For more details to implement drag and drop follow this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html